# Active Directory PowerShell creating users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
New-ADUser -SamAccountName $user.SamAccountName -Name ($user.FirstName + " " + $user.LastName) `
    -DisplayName ($user.FirstName + " " + $user.LastName) -GivenName $user.FirstName -Surname $user.LastName `
    -EmailAddress ($user.FirstName + "_" + $user.LastName + $dnsroot) -UserPrincipalName ($user.SamAccountName + $dnsroot) `
    -Title $user.title -manager $user.manager `
    -Enabled $true -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false -PasswordNeverExpires  $true `
    -AccountPassword $defpassword -PassThru `
    -AccountExpirationDate $expires -Path 'rop.com/ts/otos/ate/PMO/'` 
    -telephoneNumber "9856"'
    -LoginScript "es.cmd"'
    -Description "etant"'
    -Street "unt"`
```

I don't work with PowerShell much so I am unsure how to fix this error.

The error I get is: `Missing expression after unary operator '-'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues.

As mentioned, you need to have a space between your backticks and the end of a line for line continuation. Also, on some of your last lines, you use single quotes (') instead of backticks (`).

If your last line in the sample code is the last line of your command, having a backtick at the end of it will cause errors.

Additionally, `-telephoneNumber` is *not* a parameter of [New-ADUser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617253.aspx). The only default parameters that deal with phone numbers are `-HomePhone`, `-OfficePhone`, and `-MobilePhone`. Otherwise, you need to use the `-OtherAttributes` parameter.

In this case I think you want `-OtherAttributes @{telephonenumber="9856"}`

Comment: thank you for this because I was getting an error due to telephoneNumber not being a parameter

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you need a space before the backtick.

```
New-ADUser -SamAccountName $user.SamAccountName -Name ($user.FirstName + " " + $user.LastName) `
-DisplayName ($user.FirstName + " " + $user.LastName) -GivenName $user.FirstName -Surname $user.LastName `
-EmailAddress ($user.FirstName + "_" + $user.LastName + $dnsroot) -UserPrincipalName ($user.SamAccountName + $dnsroot) `
-Title $user.title -manager $user.manager `
-Enabled $true -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false -PasswordNeverExpires  $true `
-AccountPassword $defpassword -PassThru `
-AccountExpirationDate $expires -Path 'rop.com/ts/otos/ate/PMO/' ` 
-telephoneNumber "9856" `
-LoginScript "es.cmd" `
-Description "etant" `
-Street "unt"
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to be the problem because I still get that error

Comment: Did you copy/paste my example code? I also fixed the apostrophes which should have been backticks.

Comment: it worked now. Any idea how the apostrophe and back tick conventions work? This is my first time writing powershell for AD so I am unsure of the syntax.

Comment: not sure if you will get my message but now I get the error: Could not create user , A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'telephoneNumber'.

Comment: The backtick is the "line continuation" character. It basically means that you can span a single command across multiple lines. As for the `-TelephoneNumber` parameter, that does not exist on the `New-ADUser` command. You will need to specify the telephone number attribute using the `-OtherAttributes` parameter. Use `Get-Help New-ADUser -Param OtherAt*` for more information about the parameter.